# Liaison after past participles

Tags: liaisons

Are liaisons made between a past participle and the word that follows? I know that they are definitely not obligatory, but are they allowed (i.e. liaison facultative)?
For example:

- *"Le logiciel a été mis à jour."* Can we pronounce "mi-z-à jour" instead of "mi à jour"?
- *"Les pommes que j'ai mangées aujourd'hui..."* Can we pronounce "mangé-z-aujourd'hui"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the *liaison* is optional but rarely done in both of your sentences, outside in poetry where that would be the norm.

Comment: I am surprised a little. **Le logiciel a été mis à jour**. I do make the liaison. I don't consider it obligatory. I think without the liaison it sounds weird to me. (at least to my no native ears:-)!) I recall that I've heard several times even some native speakers to make it.

Comment: @Dimitris I don't make the liaison in that sentence. Your ears might be fooled by the proximity with *mise à jour*.

Comment: I guess you are right:-)! Merci!

Comment: On [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/search/mis/) the liaison between *mis à* and *mis en* is quite common.

Comment: @PeterShor There is a specific case *mis à part*. It can be either a single idiom meaning "outside" (*hormis*) where the liaison is mandatory or it can be a conjugated phrase where the liaison is generally not done. For the other cases, forvo.com has very few examples with *mis à* and most of them come from a single person (Pat91) who has imho a unnatural speech and probably over-corrected his diction while reading the phrases. [That one (oldking1980)](https://forvo.com/word/mis_%C3%A0_la_retraite/#fr) is much better.

Answer (score -1):

Non, dans ces 2 cas il n'y a pas de liaison.

Le logiciel a été mi- à jour.
La procédure a été mise à jour.

La terminaison en -ze est réservée au féminin.

Les pommes que j'ai mangées, ou les chocolats que j'ai mangés, ça peut paraître déroutant mais ça se prononce exactement de la même manière, qu'importe le mot qui suit.